# External authentication using Oracle Standard

Tags: linux, oracle-11g

I want to authenticate my client connections externally, using a custom external application. Is this possible using Oracle Standard 11g? If so, how?

(our custom external application will not have access to the users password, it'll just relay the requisition elsewhere)

The only documentation I found speaks of OS authentication, or using a wallet.

Comment: What operating system is the database running on?

Comment: RedHat Linux...

Comment: I presume you mean standard Oracle clients (such as SQL*Plus, SQL Developer and TOAD) connecting directly to the database over Oracle's network stack, and not some custom client apps?

Comment: No, I mean any connections to the database, such as Oracle clients, ODBC, JDBC and any other drivers...

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid it is practically impossible. In Oracle's terminology external authentication means: `"If users's name on client machine is identical to user's username in database, then user does not have to enter ANY password"`. This way of authentication is very weak and must be combined with other security features, for example you allow users to login only from one trusted, secured host.

Oracle does not support any PAM modules (like Informix for example) or whatever. The only option is how to connect Oracle to an external auth system are:

- Kerberos/RADIUS - requires Enterprise edition, plus Advanced security option, which might require extra licencing
- N-tier authentication - something like Unix su on Oracle level. But this requires support on application side.
- Password protected role enabled by Logon trigger.

Comment: There's also the Enterprise User Security option, but it also requires Enterprise Edition.

Answer (score 2):

In-fact if you need to do the external authentication for client you it can be done via external password store:

1) you need to make the password external use SHA-1 hashing algorithm. (note this is not compatible with jdbc-4).

2) open `sqlnet.ora` and make sure it contain the following line (if note you need to add it then save and close)

```
sqlnet.allowed_logon_version=12
```

or

```
sqlnet.allowed_logon_version=11
```

note that 11 and 12 depend on server specification.

3)note this step is optional and it make the password more stronger but I recommend to use it:

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET SEC_CASE_SENSITIVE_LOGON = TRUE;
```

4) you need a wallet and its used for secure authentication

5) after creating the wallet you need to list the external password content and it can be done via :

```
mkstore -wrl wallet_location -listCredential
```

6) now you need a way to make the client connect to your database for example active directory (for example oracle internet active directory) and `kerebros` authentication

** how to active LDAP authentication: `ALTER SYSTEM SET LDAP_DIRECTORY_SYSAUTH = YES;`

** how to make the connection type via password or `SSL`: `ALTER SYSTEM SET LDAP_DIRECTORY_ACCESS = XXX;` where xxx= password or `SSL` (you need to chose one of them not both).